# 'UnsafePointer<Int8>' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<_>

Tags: swift, libssh2, unsafe-pointers

I am trying to implement to write a wrapper around libssh2 using Swift. The following code is for removing a file via SFTP.

```
func removeFile(_ path: String) {
    let data = path.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let result = data.withUnsafeBytes { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int8>) -> Int in
        return libssh2_sftp_unlink_ex(sftpHandle, pointer, data.count)
    }
}
```

For `pointer: UnsafePointer<Int8>` I am getting the following error message:

```
'UnsafePointer<Int8>' is not convertible to 'UnsafePointer<_>
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742540/unsafepointeruint8-is-not-convertible-to-unsafepointer) thread about a similar Problem with `UInt8`. I tried removing the cast but was just getting the next error:

```
'Swift.UnsafePointer<_>' is not convertible to 'Swift.UnsafePointer<_>'
```

Running the `libssh2_sftp_unlink_ex(sftpHandle, pointer, data.count)` outside the closure with a dummy pointer works.

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55986029/3272409) answer on converting a String to `UInt8`, the problem is that I wasn't able to port it to `Int8`. Any ideas on how to correctly convert the pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data.withUnsafeBytes` calls the closure with an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer`, this has to be “bound” to an `UnsafePointer<Int8>`. Also `data.count` must be converted to an `UInt32` (aka `CUnsignedInt`) because that is how the C type `unsigned integer` is imported to Swift:

```
func removeFile(_ path: String) {
    let data = path.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
    let result = data.withUnsafeBytes {
        libssh2_sftp_unlink_ex(sftpHandle,
                               $0.bindMemory(to: Int8.self).baseAddress,
                               UInt32(data.count))
    }
}
```

Alternatively, use the `withCString()` method of `String`:

```
func removeFile(_ path: String) {
    let result = path.withCString {
        libssh2_sftp_unlink_ex(sftpHandle, $0, UInt32(strlen($0)))
    }
}
```

<strike>Even simpler: use the variant with needs only a C string and not an explicit string length. Here the compiler automatically creates the code to convert the Swift string to a temporary C string:</strike>

```
func removeFile(_ path: String) {
    let result = libssh2_sftp_unlink(sftpHandle, path)
}
```

(Does not work because `libssh2_sftp_unlink` is a *macro* and not imported to Swift.)

Comment: Thanks, I used the second variant `withCString()`, works perfectly.  I also tried the third approach but somehow Xcode can't find the method `libssh2_sftp_unlink`. It says unresolved identifier ...

Comment: @Codey: libssh2 defines libssh2_sftp_unlink as a macros. Apparently that macro is not imported into Swift.